# How to solve integrals where cauchy integral does not apply?

Tags: complex-analysis

Lets say I had to solve an integral over the curve with radius 2,

I have f(z) as z/(z-2), if I center z at z = 2, the residue came out to be 0.

However, my problem is if I center z at z = 2, this works but my integral would not

equal to 2pi*i*residue....because I believe residue theorem states that singularity points

must not be on the curve....can anyone help me out straighten out my logic?

Answer (score 0):

If your singularity lies on the contour, you have to evaluate the integral as a Cauchy principal value.

The contribution from the pole that lies on the contour is half of that of a pole that lies in the interior.

Comment: Stated another way: it is a divergent improper integral (in the conventional sense), so if you think it is useful anyway, you have to invent some way to make sense of it.  The Cauchy Principal Value is one of those ways.  A good example to study: $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x}$$